# Does QGIS 2.14 handle WMS redirect properly?

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm using QGIS 2.14 on Windows 7/8. I try to access a WMS version 1.3.0 set up in a DMZ and only accessible through a server running "F5 Networks" Application Delivery Control and Load Balancing software.

The first request, for the capabilities, always returns a HTTP redirect (code 302). Internet Explorer, other browsers and other GIS such as ArcGIS handle this 302 correctly. Using QGIS, I get this strange error:

> WMS Provider: Failed to download capabilities: Download of capabilities failed: Protocol "" is unknown

I was wondering if this is a known issue with QGIS and WMS redirects? In case this is an issue, what may be the solution?

PS. FYI: while ArcGIS does handle the redirect just fine, other open source GIS such as OpenJUMP en gvSIG had issues accessing the capabilities as well.

Comment: My experience is that most WMS clients do not resolve 302 redirects. Load balancing systems which modify GetCapabilities and write the real URL to use as GetMap URL into the document work better with standard clients.  However, that does not give especially dynamic load balancing.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just so you know: the problem is not that the endpoint of the capabilities differs from the endpoints distributed by the capabilities (GetMap requests and such). To solve that problem, I am using this QGIS option to "Ignore GetMap/GetTile/GetFeatureInfo URI reported in capabilities". The problem I am facing is that, due to the redirect, the capabilities themselves cannot be reached and read. Also, without the extra middleware and redirect, everything is working fine.

Comment: Selecting "Ignore GetMap/GetTile/GetFeatureInfo URI reported in capabilities" means for QGIS "Use the base URL that I wrote into the WMS address line for GetMaps".  It feels tricky to make QGIS to edit that on-the-fly with the redirection address. Right fix would be to make QGIS to follow the redirection and read GetCapabilities from that address, and on the service provider side make sure that this GetCapabilities contains a valid GetMap URL.